# Docker running out of memory when loading large sql dump

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-compose, dockerhub

I am trying to load a large sql dump to a docker postgres container and it is running out of memory.

I have set log driver to none and still running out of memory

the file is 3gb large

```
docker run -it --volume=/backend/dumps:/dumps --log-driver=none --link=postgis:postgres --rm postgres sh -c 'exec cat /dumps/databases/PostgreSQL.sql | psql -h "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR" -p "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" -U postgress -d backend_service_development'
```

Comment: How much memory has the host?

Comment: `docker run` accepts a `--memory-reservation= ` you should allocate enough, see the doc https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Comment: @RogerMiller Have you solved your problem?

Comment: it may be due to huge data in postgres. First the data gets loaded into docker container instance and then to volume folder. If you can break this chain and get data in parts and save in volume it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, it can be a bad dump, try to recreate it and retry. This helps to me.